# iOS: ADAL Auto sign-in after sign-out

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory

I am facing an issue with auto sign-in with ADAL v2.5.4 in my iOS App.

When a user wants to login to MSA account, we call acquireTokenWithResource with the required params and promptBehavior as AD_PROMPT_AUTO.
In the first run of the app, the user is shown the webview from which login flow is working as expected as user is getting logged in successfully.

On clicking ‘Sign Out’ in my app, I am removing all tokens that have my app’s ClientID. At this point I see that there is still one token present in the cache with ClientID ‘foci-1’.
Additionally I’m clearing the cookie storage of my app so that the webview doesn’t reuse any the cookies.

The issue arises when the user wishes to login again. When the same flow is triggered again for login, now the user is automatically signed in. In the logs I see ‘1 token found for query’.
Ideally since the user signed out earlier, they should be prompted for their credentials again.

What is the right way to handle this scenario?
Should sign-out be handled differently? Should there be any additional checks before login is retriggered? What is the impact of promptBehavior in this scenario?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using such an old version of ADALiOS?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to perform a "logout" from an app that uses ADAL.

It calls the logout endpoint to invalidate the refresh token on the server side and deletes all of the relevant cookies and keychain entries.

```
fileprivate var safariModal = false
fileprivate var safariHostVC: UIViewController?

public func logout(presentOn viewController: UIViewController?, modal: Bool) {

    let client = "xyzzy" // Your app client id here
    let redirect = "youruri://somepath/" // Your redirect URI here

    ADKeychainTokenCache.defaultKeychain().removeAll(forClientId: clientid, error: nil)

    if let url = URL(string:"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=\(redirect)") {
        let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        safari.toolbarItems = nil
        safari.delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            safari.dismissButtonStyle = .close
        }

        guard let vc = viewController else {
            return
        }

        self.safariHostVC = vc
        self.safariModal = modal
        safari.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        safari.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical

        if modal {
            vc.present(safari, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(safari, animated: true)
        }

        let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
        guard let cookies = cookieJar.cookies else { return }
        let cookiesArr = Array(cookies)
        for cookie: HTTPCookie in cookiesArr {
            if (cookie.name == "SignInStateCookie" || cookie.name == "ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT" || cookie.name == "ESTSAUTHLIGHT" || cookie.name == "ESTSAUTH" || cookie.name == "ESTSSC") {
                cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to implement an `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` function

```
func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    guard let vc = self.safariHostVC else {
        return
    }
    if self.safariModal {
        vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        vc.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    self.safariHostVC = nil
}
```